# How to use p12 certificate to authenticate rest api using zend http client?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, zend

How can I use p12 file/cert to authenticate to REST API using zend http client? I'm not sure how can I send request and attach that kind fo certificate.

Answer (score 0):

To send that kind of cert we just need to set adatper to CURL and set below options:

```
 $adapter = new ZendClient\Adapter\Curl();
 $adapter->setCurlOption(  CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, 'P12');
 $adapter->setCurlOption(  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
 $adapter->setCurlOption(  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```